# Check which view is on top in iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview

I have 4 views and control these view with 4 buttons, I am bit confuse that how to check that which view is on top, i already have tried with `isFirstResponder` but its not work. If anyone know please help me on that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the top most view from subViews, get the lastObject from the parent view

```
UIView * topMost = [[self.view subviews] lastObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing that used to help me at the beginning when I would try to have a setup of views that will be displayed in the same area, I used to have different background colors for every view and see which one was on top. I don't know if this is the setup you are trying to do, but the other thing you can do is flush the containing view so you only have the current view that you want on it "only".

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
[window findTopMostViewForPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
```

Functions

```
@implementation UIView (Extra)

- (UIView *)findTopMostViewForPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    for(int i = self.subviews.count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        UIView *subview = [self.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
        if(!subview.hidden && CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, point))
        {
            CGPoint pointConverted = [self convertPoint:point toView:subview];
            return [subview findTopMostViewForPoint:pointConverted];
        }
    }

    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isTopmostViewInWindow
{
    if(self.window == nil)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    CGPoint centerPointInSelf = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
    CGPoint centerPointOfSelfInWindow = [self convertPoint:centerPointInSelf toView:self.window];
    UIView *view = [self.window findTopMostViewForPoint:centerPointOfSelfInWindow];
    BOOL isTopMost = view == self || [view isDescendantOfView:self];
    return isTopMost;
}

@end
```